# На устройстве с экраном 480px срабатывают media-queries для 320px

Tags: html, адаптивная-верстка, media-queries

Внутри **<head>** добавлен мета тег

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Но не смотря на это. при заходе на сайт со смартфона с экраном 480x800px (233ppi) я вижу стили которые описаны внутри @`media screen and (max-width:320px){...}`

**Подскажите, чего не хватает или что лишнее?**

Кстати, на сайте [cssmediaqueries.com](http://cssmediaqueries.com/realtime-testing.html) этот же телефон проходит тест: @media screen  and (max-width: 480px) на отлично